# Trouble Deleting Object in Mongo Collection (Express / Monk)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, fetch, monk

I am trying and failing to delete an object from a mongo collection that I created. I can make get and post requests just fine, but I am totally lost as to how to delete an item from a given collection. I am currently just deleting the entire collection when trying to pass in the item by id...

Just so you can see what I am working with...

```
/**** IMPORTS *****/
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const monk = require('monk');

const app = express();

const db = monk('localhost/att');
// Mongo Collection packs holds package objects
const packs = db.get('packages');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
```

And my back-end delete path:

```
//packs is my collection
app.delete('/packages/:id', (req, res) => {
    packs.remove({"_id": req.body.id});
});
```

and my function on the front-end:

```
function listAllPackages() {
    fetch(API_URL_PACKAGES).then(response => response.json()).then(packageObjs => {
        // Access to all the package objects in DB here
        // packageObjs : Array of Packages
        let html = '';
        packageObjs.forEach(p => {
            html += `<option id="${p._id}" name="${p._id}">${p._id} - Name: ${p.name}, Price: ($)${p.price}, Duration: ${p.duration}(minutes)</option>`;
        });
        allPackages.innerHTML = html;
        const delPackageDiv = document.querySelector('.deletePackage');
        delPackageDiv.innerHTML = `<button id='deletePackageSubmit'>DELETE PACKAGE</button>`;
        const delPackageButton = document.querySelector('#deletePackageSubmit');
        delPackageButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // GET SELECTED PACKAGE
            const delForm = document.querySelector('.showPackages');
            const opt = delForm.options[delForm.selectedIndex];
            fetch(API_URL_PACKAGES + '/' + opt.id, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally! Here's my solution in case anyone else is struggling like I was...

Change this:

```
//packs is my collection
app.delete('/packages/:id', (req, res) => {
    packs.remove({"_id": req.body.id});
});
```

To this:

```
//packs is my collection
app.delete('/packages/:id', (req, res) => {
    packs.remove({"_id": req.params.id });
});
```

Voila!